# jCarousel slider center image

Tags: jquery, image, slider, jcarousel

I'm showing some images in a jquery jcarousel control.

I gave all images a max-width and max-height so they don't lose the original aspect.
my problem is with the small images, they are centered horizontally, but I can't get them to center vertically. they are shown on the top middle.

here's the php code I use to load images on the control:

```
<div align="center">
    <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
        <?while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {?>
           <li><img src="imagenes_bariatrica/<?=$fila["archivo"];?>" style="max- height:480px; max-width: 360px;" alt="<?=$fila["comentario"];?>"/>
            </li>
        <?}?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here's the most important jCarousel css code:

```
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
    background: #F0F6F9;
    border: 2px solid #096D0A;

}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-direction-rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-horizontal {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 20px 40px;

}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-vertical {
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    padding: 40px 20px;

}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-horizontal {
    width:  500px;
    height: 370px;

}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-vertical {
    width:  500px;
    height: 370px;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-item {
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<li>` element is probably wrapping around your images. You need to give it a fixed height, in your case I think 480px.

Then you also need to vertically center the image inside the `<li>`: this is one way to do it (I have moved here the inline style of `img` too):

```
#mycarousel li { line-height: 480px; }

#mycarousel li img { 
    max-height:     480px;
    max-width:      360px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You can use the `.jcarousel-skin-tango` selector instead of `#mycarousel` to apply to all carousels of that class.

On an unrelated note, it is best to use PHP long tags:

```
<?php
    while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>
```

For other vertical-centering methods, see [this link](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/).

Comment: if i give a fixed height most images are deformed

Comment: You don't give a fixed height to the image - only to the containing list item. The img has only a *max* size specification -- which is the one you set, at that.

Comment: do i have to set the classes to the img ?

Comment: No, jCarousel ought to set classes on its own. But try with `#mycarousel` selector first (images will be recognized by being `img` inside `li` inside `#mycarousel`). I tried with that, and it worked (I used three images, smaller, bigger, and equal to 360x480. Haven't experimented with various aspect ratios though!).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the elements are **floated**. If you want to use

```
display: table-cell; 
height: 400px;
vertical-align: middle;
```

you should also try something like

```
float: none!important;
```

on the **li** element.